# String Formatting in C# for Strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, string-formatting, strongly-typed-view

I want to know how can I convert a strong typed view Price field in to 2 digit specifier like i have got a money field in my db which converts for instance 15 into 15.0000 , i juts want to display 15.00 in the view , below is the code:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Price, new { maxlength = "5", style = "width:40px;" })%>
```

I tried something like with no success:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => String.Format("{0:n}"model.Price), new { maxlength = "5", style = "width:40px;" })%>
```

Comment: Has already been answered [here][1] :).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758573/how-to-use-a-shortdate-string-format-with-html-textboxfor/3758597#3758597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price.ToString("0.00"), new { maxlength = "5", style = "width:40px;" })%>
```

Update:

You also missed a comma in your original syntax which could be all that's stopping it from working that way too. Should have been:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => String.Format("{0:n}", model.Price), new { maxlength = "5", style = "width:40px;" })%>
```

Also, for 2 decimal places, try it like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => String.Format("{0:0.00}", model.Price), new { maxlength = "5", style = "width:40px;" })%>
```

Comment: Error:No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Mr A, I had to assume that Price was a decimal which does have a `ToString` with format parameter. What type is it?

Answer (score 3):

You can put an attribute on the model something like:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:n}")]
```

If you don't want to do that then you will need to use the 'old' style text box:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Price", string.Format("{0:n}", Model.Price)) %>
```

Comment: If I use this then I cant update , as strongly type view updates automatically

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a DataAnnotations display format attribute on your view model. Something like this:

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}")]

And then use the Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price) to render the input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mode.Price.ToString()` and specifying your desired format string in the ToString method?

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Sorry - just noticed that you're using the TextBoxFor version which I don't think accepts a format.

Answer (score 0):

this may help.

```
private DateTime hDay;  
     [DisplayName("Hire Date")]  
     [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]  
     public DateTime HireDate  
     {  
       get  
       {  
         if (hDay == DateTime.MinValue)  
         {  
           return DateTime.Today;  
         }  
         else  
           return hDay;  
       }  
       set  
       {  
         if (value == DateTime.MinValue)  
         {  
           hDay = DateTime.Now;  
         }  
       }  
     }
```

OR

we can use this way too

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MktEnquiryDetail.CallbackDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```